Propagation Method In Site Settings...How To Use?
We use multiple site options in Craft for creating sites in different languages. Here is what we want to do.
When we create a new entry in English:

It should be saved in all the sites in English language
Our translator then could edit the entry and translate it into appropriate language from English
When the entry is saved, it should be saved only for that particular language site (it should not be saved globally across each site.)

I am not sure if there is any propagation method that could do the above. We tried:

"Save Entries To All Sites Enabled...": Here, #1 works but #3 does not work because any edits made during translation are saved globally.
"Only save entries to the site they were created in" : #3 works but #1 does not work.
"Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to": Not sure how this works. According to the documentation, there should be some options in the Status section of the sidebar but I am not seeing anything.

Is there an option in the propgation method, that could do this?

You want to set your section to Save entries to all sites enabled for this section (or all sites in the same site group, depending on requirements). This will propagate the entry across all enabled sites and initially copy over the values when the entry is first published.
After the entry is propagated, you need to use field translation methods to control whether fields are translatable (can have a different value for every site) or not (all changes are immediately applied to the propagated entry in all sites). You can use different field translation methods for every field to reduce the workload for your editors, by only making fields translatable that actually need to differ between languages.

"Save Entries To All Sites Enabled...": Here, #1 works but #3 does not work because any edits made during translation are saved globally.

If you haven't configured field translation methods, all fields will default to being not translatable. That's why you're seeing this behaviour.

"Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to": Not sure how this works. According to the documentation, there should be some options in the Status section of the sidebar but I am not seeing anything.

In the entry sidebar under Status, click on the ellipsis button next to the current site:

Then you can manually select additional sites to propagate the entry to:

You will still need to configure field translation methods for your desired workflow.
If you, like me, think this is too hard to find, kindly upvote this discussion on GitHub :)
